# What to do with broken succulent leaf

Tags: succulents, damage

For our wedding favors, we ordered a variety of mini succulents in 2" pots. As one would expect, some of them were slightly damaged during shipping, with a few leaves broken in the middle. For these broken succulent leaves, is it better to clip the broken leaf off at the base, or leave the broken leaf attached?

I'm mainly asking about what's best for the health of the plant. I know with other leafier plants we have (peace lily, for example), it's better to cut off dying leaves so that the plant doesn't waste nutrients on a leaf that is going to die anyway. I wasn't sure if broken succulent leaves were doomed as well, or if they would heal and survive.

If it matters, most of the damaged plants appear to be some variety of *Echeveria*.

Comment: Just clip the broken or damaged leaves off as far down as you are able. A bigger leaf, simply sculpt a new tip using the scissors. I would definitely make a tiny how to care for this plant flyer with its botanical name to add with the plant to ensure it is cared for. Shallow pots, shallow roots, shallow infrequent watering, lots of sunlight but not outside unless acclimated. A little balanced fertilizer once settled, use potting soil only, don't make your own. Little clay pots that are shorter than tall (3 - 4") are best, no larger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think for aesthetic purpose, it would be best to clip them off at the base (a damaged leaf, broken in half, is not very pretty as a gift, is it?). I think the plant will survive such clipping. The plants are further easy to [maintain](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/ornamental/cacti-succulents/echeveria/caring-for-echeveria-plants.htm), don't over water them. You can even try to use the clipped off leaves for propagation.

Comment: Thanks, I'm mainly asking about what's best for the health of the plant. I know with other leafier plants we have (peace lily, for example), it's better to cut off dying leaves so that the plant doesn't waste nutrients on a leaf that is going to die anyway. I wasn't sure if broken succulent leaves were doomed as well, or if they would heal and survive.